# Can I use CASE WHEN outside of SELECT in SQLite/Conditional Structure in SQLite?

Tags: sqlite, conditional-statements, case

In SQL Server, I can use `IF` conditional structure to execute some statements if a condition is true. According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13654982/sqlite-case-when-statement) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43011738/conditional-query-in-sqlite), there seem to be no such structure in SQLite.

I want to check if a table exist, if it does, do nothing, if not, do a lot of things including creating tables, inserting and deleting data from other tables and updating as well:

```
CASE WHEN ((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM sqlite_master WHERE type = 'table' AND name = 'TraitsSwap') = 1) THEN
    -- 50 lines of code, including CREATE, DROP, INSERT, DELETE and UPDATE statements, with random() in used
ELSE
    -- Do nothing
END
```

Is there anyway I can achieve this? The code includes usage of `random()` and it requires consistent result (i.e, only random in the first time). I am sorry if this sounds unreasonable, but this is in context of game modding, so I cannot really change the backend code to run separated transaction code.

I think there *may* be an alternative if there is a function in SQLite that can execute a string/statement block and return a result. For that, I can transform the query into

```
SELECT CASE WHEN ((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM sqlite_master WHERE type = 'table' AND name = 'TraitsSwap') = 1) THEN
    ExecuteCode("Code; RETURN 1;")
ELSE
    0
END
```

I tried

```
SELECT CASE WHEN ((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM sqlite_master WHERE type = 'table' AND name = 'TraitsSwap') = 1) THEN
    SELECT 1;
    INSERT INTO Foo(Test) VALUES("");
    SELECT "A";
ELSE
    SELECT 1;
    SELECT 2;
    SELECT "A";
END
```

but it's unsuccessful, the error is

> near "SELECT": syntax error: SELECT CASE WHEN ((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM
>   sqlite_master WHERE type = 'table' AND name = 'TraitsSwap') = 1) THEN
>       SELECT

Comment: You can use it pretty much anywhere the grammar calls for an *expr*.

Comment: @Shawn sorry can you clarify? When I try it (my first code), it says `near "CASE": syntax error: CASE`. And then I try the 3rd code (I have just added recently), there is still another error.

Comment: @Shawn sorry they are a bit long and I think it's a bit irrelevant, but here it is: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/kaamRiwBESCCFRnW5bE7JU/0. I want to wrap them into the conditional structure.

Comment: You need parens around the case (`select (case ... end)`) but you can't have other top level statements like inserts or non-subquery selects in a case. See https://www.sqlite.org/lang.html for what sqlite understands.

Comment: @Shawn Can you write an example? I tried all possible parentheses positions but there are always syntax error near them.

Comment: You're trying to do something that you can't do. What's the point of an example?

Comment: @Shawn ah sorry I misread your previous statement. Thanks, guess I have to find another way then.

Comment: I am using better-sqlite3 which is also doing the same not allowing to use IF either CASE statement. to check it out any one can download 'https://sqlitebrowser.org/' at check it at Execute SQL tab. I have share the question as below.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73037941/any-possible-way-to-migrate-on-db-user-version-base